# Vuejs + Vite don't send JSESSIONID cookie to the backend (Tomcat). What am i doing wrong?

Tags: vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, vuejs3, vite

So I tried to find a solution on internet, found something but nothing seemed to work for me.
I have a backend in java Tomcat (no filters configured, it just serves APIs on `/api/v1/*`)

I also have a frontend in flutter that has no problem connecting to the APIs (i manually set the cookie to be sent with the requests)

And then I have a Vuejs SPA with Vite which sends requests with Axios and stores the `session` in a Pinia store.

backend is serving on `8080`

frontend on `5173`

url for login: `http://localhost:8080/bookit/api/v1/login`

url for the authorized resource: `http://localhost:8080/bookit/api/v1/users`

my `vite.config.ts` file is:

```ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api/v1": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080/bookit",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

then i do login with basic auth using axios like this:

```ts
async function login() {
  axios.get("/api/v1/login", {
      withCredentials: true,
      auth: {
        username: username.value,
        password: password.value,
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      // here i store the session id in a pinia store
  });
}
```

and finally, when I'm trying to fetch some authorized data, i get `401` from my backend (new session is created because no cookie with JSESSIONID was received):

```ts
async function callApi() {
  axios
    .get("/api/v1/users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + session,
        Cookie: `JSESSIONID=${session}; Path=/bookit; HttpOnly;`,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
});
```

When I look at the cookies exchanged between client and server, there is the response cookie but obviously no request cookie. Also, the `xhr.js` is yelling at me in the console saying:
`Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Cookie`. So here I am, given up research bc nothing seems to solve my issue. I'll greatly appreciate any help or hint

I tried with this proxy config:

```ts
proxy: {
     "/api/v1": "http://localhost:8080/bookit",
},
```

Tried adding and removing `withCredentials = true` but nothing..there's something I'm missing here